# Composite transformation matrix

Tags: matrices

[image: composite stuff]

How to go about calculating the composite transformation matrix? Aren't we supposed to calculate from right to left (just like functions)? If so, why is computation in the picture showing otherwise?

Comment: welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!

Comment: Associativity of matrix product.